# iOS - Deeplink doesn't work if app is inactive

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, deep-linking

I'm implementing deeplink for ios -> react native.

I know the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be triggered if the app is in-active.
But putting these code won't help passing deeplink inside the app

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...
  if(launchOptions) {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSURL *siteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[userInfo objectForKey:@"url"]];
    if(siteURL) {
//      [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result){}];
//      return [self application:application openURL:siteURL options:launchOptions];
      return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:siteURL options:launchOptions];
    }
  }
  return Yes;
}
```

The siteURL is valid but I've tried above ways but none of them work.

This is openURL method, which will never be called if app is inactive

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  NSLog(@"123456xx %@",url.absoluteString);
  NSString *myUrl = url.absoluteString;
  if ([myUrl containsString:@"fb***"]) {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                               annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                    ];
    } else {
      return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
    }
//  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

And `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  NSLog(@"123456 did receive");
  // redirect while got url from notif
  NSString *urlstr = (NSString*)[userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
  if(urlstr) {
    NSLog(@"123456 did receive url %@", urlstr);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:@{}];
  }


  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also implement the `openURL` delegate method like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    // handle deeplinks here.
}
```

From there you can handle the opening of the URL even if your app is "in-active" as you said.

Comment: I already have, updated the question, openURL is never be called if app is inactive

Comment: Not sure what you're missing anymore, but you could try `applicationDidBecomeActive`. Since this method is called regardless of your app state. See its documentation. Perhaps you're retuning `NO` in willFinish or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: I notice there is the log with error: `finished with error [-1101] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1101 "file is directory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=file is directory, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<private>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=<private>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=<private>` , but since url is valid for active app.

Comment: After a while investigation, i realised this is ios error, closed/killed app would not receive deeplink: https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal/issues/1016

Comment: I see. Thanks for sharing. I didn't notice the tag react native. And not sure how it works, but ideally, even with closed/killed state, deeplink should be working.